# Add a value to a url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a big issue here.
I have a site example.com, due to the way it was coded, example.com is different from example.com/index. How can i use htaccess to redirect all incoming request from example.com to example.com/index

Here is what i've tried to do but it's not working
The first i did was

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/index/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second was

```
RewriteRule ^/index/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php [L]
```

I'm not so familiar with htaccess though. Any help?

Thanks

**NOTE** there are so many domain the .htaccess file is working for and i want the rule to affect all e.g example.com should go to example.com/index, example1.com should go to example1.com/index and ... like that

And i already have this rule on top `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule in the website root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /index [L,R=302]
```

This will redirect:

```
example.com => example.com/index
example1.com => example1.com/index
```

Comment: `^/?$` pattern only matches landing page i.e. `example.com/` and `/index` is the target URL.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't have enough reputation to mark the answer as the right one. When i get enough reputation i will.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```